# Is there public domain prior art for frost-breathing Winter Wolves?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, intellectual-property

Does anyone know of any public domain prior art for the breath weapon of D&D's winter wolf? I ask because I'd like to use ice-breathing wolves in fiction, but would have to avoid litigation in doing so.

I don't know whether there's any frost breath in mythology, but I'm not an expert on mythology either, and I don't know whether this concept stretches back to antiquity/prehistory.

In my Googling I saw that there are apparently winter wolves in *A Song of Ice and Fire* (which I haven't seen much of), but from what I was able to find there's nothing about them breathing frost.

Comment: It seems that you have two questions: The cultural/mythological basis of the attack and the -Am I going to be sued if I use the name "frost breath" for my -insert work here-? Any of them will give you different answers, and I think you want the later rather than the first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to need RPG expertise, but rather cultural/historical/literary expertise.

Comment: It may be better off asked on [scifi.se]. Note that you can *always* be frivolously sued by anyone baselessly in most places in the world, it'll just take time & money to demonstrate the lawsuit is baseless and have it dismissed or defend the allegations.

Comment: [Mythology.se] SE is also a possibility for a question that is specifically narrowed to just whether there is a precedent in mythology.

Answer (score 2):

I find several different sources that use "Frost Breath".

1. D&D : Winter Wolves
2. Pokemon : Pokemon Go has 5 pokemon with this power
3. Skyrim : A Dragonborn shout power
4. Magic:TheGathering : Instant card that taps two creatures and prevents them from untapping on the next upkeep
5. Guild Wars 2 : Spell

With these varied sources, I don't think you are in any danger of being sued for using "Frost Breath".